# ClearCase: how to revert a change in my snapshot view?

Tags: clearcase, revert, cleartool

My problem:

I have a snapshot view of my stream. I made some changes locally in this snapshot for testing. Now, I delivered new code to the stream and ran "cleartool update" on my snapshot. However, this did not overwrite the files that I modified in my snapshot. I can still see my temporary changes.

Can I somehow revert my local snapshot changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **[`cleartool update`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm)** won't touch your locally modified files by default
You would need to add an option like `-overwrite` for that, for restoring the content of hijacked file.

If you checked out files to do your temporary modifications, then you would need to undo-checkout those files before doing a cleartool update.